# Microsoft Media Foundation Transform (MFT) with C#?

Tags: c#, ms-media-foundation

Does anyone know if Microsoft MFTs for Win7 can be written in C#? If so, is there any book or website that would help me in this.

Answer (score 3):

MFTs can definitely be written in C#. Maybe checkt out the managed wrapper around the MF Api´s at [sourceforge](http://mfnet.sourceforge.net). it´s more or less just a managed definition of interfaces and GUIDs for COM interaction that can be used within .NET. just implemented the right interfaces, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940441(VS.85).aspx).
However, i find some parts a little bit tricky (e.g. rate control), but depending on the type of MFT you want to create you maybe don´t need to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

The MF Team blog could help:

http://blogs.msdn.com/mf/default.aspx

The team started posting in November of 2009.

Comment: and stopped posting more than 1 year ago. i.e around Jan 2011